# Python sum pairs from text file

Tags: python

I am given a sorted array of positive integers and a number X and I need to print out all pairs of numbers whose sum is equal to X. Print out only unique pairs and the pairs should be in ascending order.

However the program needs to read lines of text from standard input where each line contains a comma separated list of sorted numbers, followed by a semicolon, followed by the integer X.

e.g. test input:`1,2,3,4,6;5`
output: `1,4;2,3`

I have tried

```
list1 = []
for line in sys.stdin:
    for n in line:
        list1.append(n)
        strlist = [ x for x in list1 if x.isdigit() ]
        numlist = list(map(int, strlist))
    sum = numlist[-1]
    res = []
    while numlist:
        num = numlist.pop()
        diff = sum - num
        if diff in numlist:
            res.append((diff, num))     
    res.reverse()
    print(res, end="")
```

But i get

Test Input: `1,2,3,4,6;5`

Expected Output: `1,4;2,3`

My Output: `[(2, 3), (1, 4)]`

Comment: what u have tried?

Comment: Please read [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You need to show what your specific issue is by sharing your code and the error you are getting.

Comment: why do you reverse your result?

Comment: @diggusbickus yes sorry i should have removed that i was trying something

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the most efficient, but I came up with this that worked.

Replace the test_case with sys.stdin and remove the test_case should work.

Sorry if this looks bad, it's my first time posting on stackoverflow.

```
test_case = ["1,2,3,4,6;5"]
for line in test_case:
    line = line.split(";")
    numbers = line[0].split(",")
    pairs = []
    for number in numbers:
        difference = int(line[1]) - int(number)
        difference = str(difference)
        if  difference in numbers and difference != number:
            pair = ",".join((number, difference))
            pairs.append(pair)
del pairs[len(pairs)//2:len(pairs)]
print(";".join(pairs))
```

Output : 1,4;2,3

Comment: Presumably this will fail on `"2,2;4"` because of the `difference != number` test. Also, the test `difference in numbers` is pretty inefficient if `numbers` is a list. It would be more efficient if you first built a `set` or a `collections.Counter` from the list

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1:

Time complexity of `O(n^2)`. This is based on the original solution. The corrections made were:

- The iteration of the string and parsing per character wouldn't work for 2-digit numbers (or more) e.g. `12` thus it is incorrect. Also it is not efficient. Instead of manually iterating each character, checking `.isdigit()`, and then redoing it again for the next number for the whole list, just split the string by the characters `;` and `,` and then transform them to int.
- In your original logic, the target sum would be the last element in the list `numlist`. But you are considering that number for the sum (since it will be the first number to be popped out). You should pop it first before entering the while loop.
- The order of the pairs would start from the highest number (pop until list is empty). So, the pair for the highest number would be the smallest number e.g. `1` is to `4`, then `2` is to `3`, thus no need to call `.reverse()` as it will do the opposite.

```
for input_text in [
    "1,2,3,4,6;5",
    "5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45;50",
    "0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14;12",
]:
    num_str, sum_str = input_text.split(';')
    num_list = list(map(int, num_str.split(',')))
    target_sum = int(sum_str)

    res = []
    while num_list:
        num = num_list.pop()
        diff = target_sum - num
        if diff in num_list:
            res.append((diff, num))     
    res_formatted = ";".join(map(lambda pair: f"{pair[0]},{pair[1]}", res))
    print(f"{input_text}\n\t{res}\n\t{res_formatted}")
```

### Solution 2:

Time complexity of `O(n)`. Since we already have sorted data, instead of iterating the whole list finding the other number that will arrive to the target sum for each number, just use 2 pointers, one at the start/left `lhs` and one at the end/right `rhs`.

- If the sum is **lower** than the target, then it means that we need to move forward/right the `lhs`. Why? Because if we already added it to the maximum number which is `rhs`, then there is no point of trying it with the other numbers. What we need is to increase `lhs` and see the next result.
- If the sum is **higher** than the target, then it means we need to move back/left the `rhs`. Why? Same point as above, If the sum was already higher, then we can't use the number in `rhs` as it is too high even if added with the smallest number `lhs`, thus move it to the next smaller number.
- If the sum is **equal** to the target sum, then we include in the result the numbers pointed to by `lhs` and `rhs`. Then we move both pointers respectively.

```
def sum_pairs(numbers, target_sum):
    lhs = 0
    rhs = len(numbers) - 1
    pairs = []
    while lhs < rhs:
        current_sum = numbers[lhs] + numbers[rhs]
        if current_sum == target_sum:
            pairs.append((numbers[lhs], numbers[rhs]))
            lhs += 1
            rhs -= 1
        elif current_sum > target_sum:
            rhs -= 1
        else:
            lhs += 1

    return pairs

for input_text in [
    "1,2,3,4,6;5",
    "5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45;50",
    "0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14;12",
]:
    num_str, sum_str = input_text.split(';')
    num_list = list(map(int, num_str.split(',')))
    target_sum = int(sum_str)

    res = sum_pairs(num_list, target_sum)

    res_formatted = ";".join(map(lambda pair: f"{pair[0]},{pair[1]}", res))
    print(f"{input_text}\n\t{res}\n\t{res_formatted}")
```

**Output**

```
1,2,3,4,6;5
    [(1, 4), (2, 3)]
    1,4;2,3
5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45;50
    [(5, 45), (10, 40), (15, 35), (20, 30)]
    5,45;10,40;15,35;20,30
0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14;12
    [(0, 12), (2, 10), (4, 8)]
    0,12;2,10;4,8
```